# Unable to fetch javascript files in aws

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, amazon-ec2

I have to plot graph using javascript in HTML, I'm using flask as webframework. But I'm unable to fetch the javascripts. I have separate folders for templates(contains HTML file) and static(contains css and js files).
here is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Load c3.css -->
    <link href="./static/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
    <script src="./static/d3.v3.min.js"charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="./static/c3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<br><br><br>
    
<div class="container">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>

    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;margin: 30px;">Architecture Building</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post" style="text-align:center; margin: 20px;">
                <input type="text" name="Week" placeholder="Week" required="required" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Predict</button>
        </form>
        {{ prediction_text }}
        <div class="container">
            <div id="chartContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="./static/arch.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

[image: Directory in AWS]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

The '.' from the beginning of those URLs for those static is causing the normal routing for static to get bypassed. Remove them.

Comment: Update your post then. And If you're still seeing `/file://` in the logs, are you making any config changes to the Flask instance? Can you show us that code, too?